# Is there any way to sum a column in rdlc by matching previous column?

Tags: rdlc

Is there any way to sum a column in rdlc by matching previous column? Let say I have a Code_No column and the Value of this column may be duplicate. I want to sum its left column only if the value of this Code_No column are different.

Comment: Can you provide a minimal code please ?

Comment: =Sum(CDec(iif(Previous(Fields!refno.Value <> Fields!refno.Value), Fields!realval.Value,0)))

refno             realval
C101            120.20
C101            120.20
C102            220.50
C101            120.20
C102            220.50

My desired result is (120.20+220.50) @ma3oun